# Strdup returning address out of bounds

Tags: c

I thought I'd ask before spending more hours on this. Valgrind doesn't report anything, in fact it doesn't crash with Valgrind.

```
char* a = "HI";
char* b = strdup(a);
```

(gdb) print b => 
`$8 = 0xffffffffe8003680 <Address 0xffffffffe8003680 out of bounds>`

This only happens in my dynamically loaded shared library, (loaded with dlopen). I have no idea what could possibly cause this. I stripped just about everything out of that library, there are only these two lines in it. Can you help me debug this?

If I try to access `b` now:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff76b3d0a in strchrnul () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

What could possibly be going wrong here?

*Backtrace:*

> ```
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x00007ffff76b3d0a in strchrnul () from /lib64/libc.so.6
> (gdb) bt
> #0  0x00007ffff76b3d0a in strchrnul () from /lib64/libc.so.6
> #1  0x00007ffff767088a in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
> #2  0x00007ffff767af79 in printf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
> #3  0x00007ffff722678c in _mkp_stage_30 (plugin=0x61f420, cs=0x7fffe8002040, 
>     sr=0x7fffe8003070) at hello.c:68
> #4  0x000000000040f93a in mk_plugin_stage_run (hook=16, socket=18, conx=0x0, 
>     cs=0x7fffe8002040, sr=0x7fffe8003070) at mk_plugin.c:558
> #5  0x000000000040c501 in mk_http_init (cs=0x7fffe8002040, sr=0x7fffe8003070)
>     at mk_http.c:255
> #6  0x0000000000404870 in mk_request_process (cs=0x7fffe8002040, 
>     sr=0x7fffe8003070) at mk_request.c:510
> #7  0x0000000000404d75 in mk_handler_write (socket=18, cs=0x7fffe8002040)
>     at mk_request.c:630
> #8  0x000000000040b446 in mk_conn_write (socket=18) at mk_connection.c:130
> #9  0x0000000000409352 in mk_epoll_init (efd=12, handler=0x7fffe8001690, 
>     max_events=202) at mk_epoll.c:102
> #10 0x0000000000409b4e in mk_sched_launch_worker_loop (thread_conf=0x61a5a0)
>     at mk_scheduler.c:196
> #11 0x00007ffff79c2f05 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
> #12 0x00007ffff770553d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
> ```

Comment: Can you get a backtrace (i.e. run bt) in gdb after the SIGSEGV and show the output?

Comment: Thanks! What are you printing with printf(), that shows up at #2? I just created a simple program that calls dlopen() and a .so that simply has your code above (with a printf() for the two strings) in a constructor, and it compiles and runs without issue.

Comment: @Blub: Could you post your actual code (perhaps shortening it to the bare minimum that still exhibits the problem)? I have a strong feeling that there are other things going on in the code that we haven't been shown yet.

Comment: @DanFego I just printf(b); to make it crash. You know what's strange? If I compile with clang, clang complains that I need to include <string.h> to explicitly declare strdup(). But I already do! In any case, this is the entire source code, it's a starter plugin for the monkey http webserver: https://gist.github.com/45af6aff2237c0d90cc4

Comment: the adresses that you show us curiously look as if there has been a 32/64 bit clash from the return of `strdup`. If clang complains there must be something really fishy with your includes. Perhaps some files defines the include guards of another file or something like that.

Comment: What compiler warnings are you getting and ignoring?  Which ones are you asking for?  In particular, is `strdup()` declared?  If not, then the compiler will assume it returns an integer (4 bytes) and then extend that to create the pointer - rather than taking all 8 bytes returned and treating that as the pointer.

Comment: I compiled the part without your includes and there is no problem (for the compilation) for both gcc or clang.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm getting different warnings from clang and gcc. Compiled with clang, it works. Compiled with gcc, it doesn't and it returns these warning: https://gist.github.com/0c41fe04e9eebeaa100f  Pointer from what integer? Why would strdup() return an integer

Comment: @Blub: As Jonathan said above, if it's not found as being declared (which it might not be, depending on your defines), then it assumes the function returns int. I think it's a C thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add

```
#include <string.h>
```

to get the declaration of `strdup()`.

Or, if you already have that, you need to invoke your compiler in a way that makes `strdup()` visible (see below for details).  `strdup()` is defined by POSIX, not by ISO C.

gcc enables the appropriate macro(s) by default, but using `-ansi` or `-std=c99` will disable them.  You can also add an appropriate `#define` to the top of your source file.

In the absence of a visible declaration, the compiler assumes (under C90 rules) that `strdup()` returns `int`.  This results in undefined behavior.  In particular, if `int` is 32 bits and `char*` is 64 bits, Bad Things Will Happen.  (Under C99 rules, calling a function with no visible declaration is a constraint violation.)

You should also crank up your compiler's warning levels and *pay attention to the warnings*.  A problem like this should manifest at compile time; you shouldn't have to diagnose the run-time behavior.

**UPDATE :**

The following is based on documentation and experiments on my own Ubuntu 11.04 system.  It's likely to apply to any system using glibc; some of it might apply to non-glibc systems.  `man strdup` and `man feature_test_macros` for more information.

To use `strdup()`, you *must* have `#include <string.h>` to make the declaration visible.  (The compiler won't necessarily complain if you omit this, but you need it anyway.)

In addition, you need to have one of the following (or equivalent) *before* the `#include <string.h>`:

```
#define _SVID_SOURCE
```

---

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
```

---

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500 /* or greater */
```

---

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED
```

---

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L /* or greater */
```

The simplest way to do this is just *not* to use the `-ansi` or `-std=...` option for gcc (or the equivalent for clang); gcc enables some of these macros by default.

If you want to compile with `-ansi` or `std=c99`, then you can explicitly set one of the above macros (or two if you use the 4th alternative), either with an explicit `#define` in the source (probably the best solution), or by using, for example, `gcc -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500`.

*And*, as I mentioned before, you should crank up the warning levels on your compiler.  For gcc, I typically use:

```
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O3
```

The `-O3` enables optimizations; a side effect is that it enables the analysis necessary to perform those optimizations, which can detect a number of problems that aren't apparent at lower optimization levels.

The reason for all this rigmarole is that `strdup()` is not defined by the ANSI/ISO C standard (the committee chose not to include it), but it is defined by POSIX -- and its declaration is in `<string.h>`, one of the ISO C standard headers.  In strict ISO C conforming mode, the name `strdup()` may not be made visible in `<string.h>`.  You have to take these extra steps to tell the compiler to make it visible anyway.  (gcc is not a fully conforming C compiler by default, which is why it's able to make `strdup()` visible by default.)

Since `strdup()` is such a simple function, you might consider just writing your own implementation in standard ISO C and using that instead.  For example (note that names starting with `str` are reserved):

```
char *dupstr(const char *s) {
    char *const result = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    if (result != NULL) {
        strcpy(result, s);
    }
    return result;
}
```

(I have only minimally tested this.)  If `strdup()` is the only POSIX-specific function you're using, rolling your own might be the best solution.  If you're using other POSIX-specific functions, then you'll have to deal with all this stuff anyway, and you might as well use `strdup()` itself.

Comment: I'm trying to "detect" if there is `strdup()` avaliable,if so,us it. Otherwise use my onw implementation. But isn't working,I'm on POSIX enviroment,but I'm still used my onw implementation. Check out how I'm performing it: `#if defined(_SVID_SOURCE) || defined(_BSD_SOURCE) || defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) && _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 || \
  defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) && defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED)
/* there is strdup() avaliable */
/* in this header */
#include <string.h> 
#else
char*
strdup(const char *src)
{
  printf("coping src: [%s]!!\n", src);
  return memdup(&src[0], sizeof(src));
}
#endif`

Comment: `memdup()` is my implementation to duplicate a memory block. It simple too: `void *memdup(void *src,size_t size);` `size` is passed to `malloc()` its return-value is stored in a `void *tmp` that's checked for non-NULL value,and then `return memcpy(tmp,src,size)`

Comment: If your program depends on POSIX for other reasons, `strdup()` should be available anyway. If not, it's probably easier just to use your own `strdup()`-like function unconditionally. (Don't use the name `strdup()`; it's reserved to the implementation.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're incorrectly calling printf(). Rather than printf(b), you need to do:

```
printf("%s\n", b);
```

**Edit:** Added \n above, thanks to Jonathan.

Comment: To be moderately sure of seeing the result, that format needs to be `"%s\n"` or even `"b = <<%s>>\n"`.  However, with the given data ("HI"), the plain `printf(b)` should work, albeit not very safely.

Comment: But this is no reason to have a segfault, no? "HI" doesn't contain any `%` or so, so this should just get printed.

Comment: Perhaps it's not the reason, but the crash does seem to stem from the printf(), and having the function be called the way it's supposed to is a good first step in figuring out why there is.

Comment: Well this is disappointing, because it works now but it doesn't make any sense what-so-ever. I literally just came back from a walk with my dog, saw your post, inserted the "%s\n" string..and it worked. Then I removed the string again, and...it still works. I now have a plain printf(b) just like before and it doesn't segfault. So I have no idea what in the world is going on. I must somehow have had a faulty installation, since I just reinstalled opensuse. If that counts as an "explanation". Still thanks for all your help, can you explain why <<%s>> is safer than %s?

Comment: @Blub: I've been there before... I hate that! I think Jonathan was suggesting that you do that so you can easily tell that both the line was printed and what the string is, since you have markers for where it's supposed to start and end.

Comment: Hm, perhaps you need to define some macros during compilation? According to my (Linux) man page, strdup requires _SVID_SOURCE || _BSD_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 || _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED || _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L. Or before glibc 2.12, _SVID_SOURCE || _BSD_SOURCE || XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 || _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED.

Comment: Dan, I just deleted the former comment because I concluded the thing a little too hastily. Turns out I was testing with clang to get those warnings. The whole thing still reliably segfaults when compiled with gcc. Here the warnings again:https://gist.github.com/0ccb85a51ab56e05829c . I'll try something with the macros

Comment: @Blub: Do you get any warnings if you compile with gcc -Wall?

Comment: @DanFego, yes I just tried that, I made a comment above. strdup() for some reason returns an integer?!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5535/discussion-between-blub-and-dan-fego)