# what's wrong with my clean function?

Tags: c

I want to write a function clearing any string from numbers and signs like !@#$%^&*()_+ but always I get this error: *** glibc detected**  ./clear: invalid fastbin entry (free): 0x0000000001d29490 **

Here's the code:

```
void clean(char *dirty)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char *temp;

    temp = strdup(dirty);
    while(i < strlen(temp))
    {
        if(isalpha(temp[i]) && isspace(temp[i]))
        {
            dirty[j] = temp[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    dirty[j] = '\0';
    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: why isalpha(temp[i]) && isspace(temp[i]) true at the same time?

Comment: apart from the logic-flaw that everybody points out (invalid use of `&&` instead of `||`), there is nothing really wrong with your function. most likely the problem is somewhere else (e.g. the way you call the function)

Comment: This function seems to be ok except the logic, the free error could be in other part of code. memory allocated with `strdup` can be freed using `free`. can you please post some more code??

Comment: The code you show is **not** the reason for the crash you observer. Please show us how `clean()` is called and how the variable passed into is declared.

Comment: Ugh; you're using `strlen` in the condition of a loop. While that won't cause a crash, it's thoroughly inefficient (turning an O(N) operation into an O(N²) one). Just check for `temp[i]=='\0'`.

Comment: Your code might crash if temp happens to be a nullpointer, then you try to free memory that has not been allocated.

Comment: @DonalFellows: I have not checked it but I expect the compiler to manage that. `size_t strlen ( const char * str );` shows that `str` is not modified and in the loop `temp` is not changed either. Compilers can move constant expressions out of loops.

Comment: @ted I would not expect the compiler to be _required_ to figure out that it is constant in this case; counting on it to do so would be unwise when the correct thing to do is so easy.

Comment: One more thing to check which nobody has mentioned yet: Does your input string contain a '\0' character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for the return value of `strdup`. If the memory allocation encountered problems (e.g. not enough memory), `temp` gets the value `NULL`. Check if that is the case and exit with an error message.

---

Your if statement is always false:

```
if(isalpha(temp[i]) && isspace(temp[i]))
```

How could `temp[i]` be both alphanumerical **and** space?

---

Note also (although it's not the question) that this is rather a job for `for` than `while` (looping through all elements of an array until its end). It's always good to use the expected idiom.

This could also be done in place (no need for a `temp` string):

```
dirty[j] = dirty[i];
```

since `i` is greater or equal to `j`.

Comment: This does not explain why the program crashes.

Comment: A `NULL` in `temp` would most certainly explain it.

Comment: Guys, it's **not** about `free()`ing a `NULL` pointer, but about passing it to `strlen()` and if the program should unexpectedly survive this about implicitly dereferencing it using the `[]` operator.

Comment: @ted What is it about `free(NULL)`? Did you try it yourself? That's guaranteed to do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

There could be several reasons causing the OP's code to crash:

**1**  `strdup()` returned `NULL`.

Test its result:

```
char * temp = strdup();
if (NULL == temp)
{
  perror("strdup()" failed");
  return;
}
```

---

**2** On a 64bit system: `strdup()`'s prototype is missing

Include the appropriate header **and**, as it's **not** a standrd C, function make sure it is defined in there:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L /* or greater */ /* for gcc us option -std=c99  */
#include <string.h>
```

As per *[lulyon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1607051/lulyon)*'s comment: For various other possibe `#define` enabling `strdup()` protoyping please [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8361259/694576).

---

**3** The string passed to `clean(char * dirty)` is `NULL`

Perform input validation:

```
if (NULL == dirty)
{
  perror("invalid input");
  return;
}
```

---

**4** The string passed to `clean(char * dirty)` referrs to an unmutable constant

Do **not** call clean

- like this:

  ```
  char * dirty = "*ç%&/*alk  42";
  clean(dirty);
  ```
- neither like this:

  ```
  clean("*ç%&/*alk  42");
  ```
- nor like this:

  ```
  #define dirty "*ç%&/*alk  42"
  clean(dirty);
  ```

---

**5** (As per [Mike Hartl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/797637/mike-hartl)'s comment) The string passed to `clean(char * dirty)` is missing its `0`-termination

Undetectable from inside `clean()`, so fix the input.

Comment: `NULL` pointer would of course result in a `Segmentation fault`. Isn't it? And by the way `NULL` to `free` does not perform any operation. man 3 free.

Comment: @SakthiKumar: A `NULL` pointer itself would cause nothing. Dereferencing it would cause undefined behaviour, which itself then could cause **anything**. Did I wrote `free()`ing a `NULL`-pointer would cause issues?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isalpha(temp[i]) && isspace(temp[i]))      // logic AND. The character could not be both alpha and space
```

should be

```
if(isalpha(temp[i]) || isspace(temp[i]))      // logic OR.
```

The remaining part of code is of no problem.

Update:

The code works fine on my Window PC. So here I can only recommend checking `errno` to find what is wrong.

One more thing, check the pointer `char *dirty` and `char *temp` if they are empty before using them.

Update:

a useful link that explains `strdup`: [Strdup returning address out of bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359966/strdup-returning-address-out-of-bounds)

Comment: This does not explain why the program crashes.

Comment: @alk I've explain that "The remaining part of code is of no problem". The code works fine on my Window PC. However, `strdup` function might cause problem under Linux. http://www.unix.com/programming/181243-glibc-detected-malloc-memory-corruption-fast.html. So thanks for pointing out.

Comment: "*... strdup function might cause problem under Linux ...*" the link you posted does **not** show any problem using `strdup()`. And I strongly doubt that there are any issues with `strdup()`'s stability in any recent implementation. You better not spread rumors around here.

Comment: @alk I am not spreading rumors, because "The code works fine on my Window PC.", and see The 3rd floor of the link http://www.unix.com/programming/181243-glibc-detected-malloc-memory-corruption-fast.html#3, where a issue is reported. So I made the deduction. I do not mean strdup have problem in general case, but in this context.

Comment: Dear *lulyon*: The posting you linked refers to `strdup()` as "***resolving***" an issue by **using** `strdup()` **instead** of `strcpy()`.

Comment: @alk Yes, you are right. My mistake. Thanks. Then I can only seek for checking `errno` to find the secret behind.

Comment: @alk I think this post explains everything about strdup and problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359966/strdup-returning-address-out-of-bounds. What do you think?

Comment: As also my answer does ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your loop seems to be flawed. This will never hold

```
isalpha(temp[i]) && isspace(temp[i])
```

so `j` will always be `0` at the end.

Comment: This does not explain why the program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

If you work under linux, You may consider valgrind usage for memory problems detection